# IdentityServer4 and Azure AD auto selects users on sign-in page

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, identityserver4, openid-connect

Recently it seems like Microsoft changed something in the behaviour when people are trying to sign-in with their Microsoft Account through our services.

We have a setup where we use IdentityServer4 and Azure AD for the Microsoft Accounts. When people try to sign-in now, they just click sign-in button on our webpage and is taken to the Microsoft sign-in. Here it seems that Microsoft is automatically selecting the already logged in user and just proceeds to log the user in.

This leads to two issues.

1. It is a hard for the user to understand that their account is just automatically selected.
2. If the user is fast enough, they can click their user and that sends two callbacks to our server and a race-condition happens, which results in an `OperationCancelledException` half of the time.

Our setup is pretty close to the one given as example on IdentityServer4s Quick start guide:

```
serviceCollection
    .AddAuthentication(o =>
    {
        o.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        o.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftAccount("Microsoft", "Microsoft", o =>
    {
        o.SignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
        o.ClientId = _externalKeysOptions.MicrosoftClientId;
        o.ClientSecret = _externalKeysOptions.MicrosoftClientSecret;
        o.CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-microsoft");
        new[]
        {
            "offline_access",
            "Calendars.Read.Shared",
            "Calendars.ReadWrite",
            "Tasks.Readwrite"
        }.ForEach(scope => o.Scope.Add(scope));
        o.SaveTokens = true;
    })
```

We setup the authentication schemes as above. And then we do a normal challenge against the provider:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[Route("externallogin")]
public IActionResult ExternalLogin(ExternalLoginModel model)
{
    var redirectUrl = Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", "Account", new { model.ReturnUrl, termsOfServiceAccepted = model.AgreeToTerms, platform = model.Platform });
    var properties = _signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(model.Provider, redirectUrl);

    return Challenge(properties, model.Provider);
}
```

Does anybody have any knowledge of why this is happening. I would really like to disable this auto-selection of the users account when they are using Microsoft login. Because it is mostly confusing our customers instead of helping them.

Any resources are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as I know this is due to the browser. If a user uses a browser that has Microsoft credentials already entered in for another tab for example this will happen. Recommend your user use incognito or a different browser to assess this. There's no real way around it. Managing identities is something users will have to get used to.

Comment: @SimonBourdeau I have a hard time figuring out if this is actually the browser or the page. Because it is not consistent across Microsoft login pages. Which makes me think it is not the browser.

Comment: You say it is not consistent across login pages, can it be that some logins are driven from cloud AAD (Azure Active Directory) and some from on premise Active Directory managed domains? Our SaaS product runs into loads of these MS login issues because we use invited users into our AAD. We have identified numerous error paths that involve new Office 365 installs for example. Some solutions involve deletion and re-invite, some are just a hard clear cache refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I finally figured out what the problem was. I think that Microsoft have changed to using OIDC as the authentication method.

That means we are now able to send along a `prompt` paramter in the query string.

From the OIDC [documentation](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#Authentication):

```
prompt
OPTIONAL. Space delimited, case sensitive list of ASCII string values that specifies whether the Authorization Server prompts the End-User for reauthentication and consent. The defined values are:
   none
     The Authorization Server MUST NOT display any authentication or consent user interface pages. An error is returned if an End-User is not already authenticated or the Client does not have pre-configured consent for the requested Claims or does not fulfill other conditions for processing the request. The error code will typically be login_required, interaction_required, or another code defined in Section 3.1.2.6. This can be used as a method to check for existing authentication and/or consent.
   login
     The Authorization Server SHOULD prompt the End-User for reauthentication. If it cannot reauthenticate the End-User, it MUST return an error, typically login_required.
   consent
     The Authorization Server SHOULD prompt the End-User for consent before returning information to the Client. If it cannot obtain consent, it MUST return an error, typically consent_required.
   select_account
     The Authorization Server SHOULD prompt the End-User to select a user account. This enables an End-User who has multiple accounts at the Authorization Server to select amongst the multiple accounts that they might have current sessions for. If it cannot obtain an account selection choice made by the End-User, it MUST return an error, typically account_selection_required.
```

That means we now need to add `prompt=select_account` to the query params when we challenge the user.

Unfortunately the MicrosoftAccount nuget package does not support this right now. So I had to add a little hack for it to work:

```
.AddMicrosoftAccount("Microsoft", "Microsoft", o =>
{
    o.SignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
    o.ClientId = _externalKeysOptions.MicrosoftClientId;
    o.ClientSecret = _externalKeysOptions.MicrosoftClientSecret;
    o.CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-microsoft");
    new[]
    {
        "offline_access",
        "Calendars.Read.Shared",
        "Calendars.ReadWrite",
        "Tasks.Readwrite",
        "openid"
    }.ForEach(scope => o.Scope.Add(scope));
    o.SaveTokens = true;
    o.Events = new OAuthEvents
    {
        OnRedirectToAuthorizationEndpoint = context =>
        {
            var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(context.RedirectUri);
            var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uriBuilder.Query);
            query["prompt"] = "select_account";
            uriBuilder.Query = query.ToString();
            var newRedirectUri = uriBuilder.ToString();
            context.Response.Redirect(newRedirectUri);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };
})
```

The code that fixed it was `OnRedirectToAuthorizationEndpoint` where I add the query param to URL.